# Multiselect checkboxes value show on button vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a multi-select ui component where i have to push selected values to an array and show the same in a button value. I am getting the selected values in alert box but not able to get it in button.

Please help me to show the selected items values as button value as soon as the checkbox clicked.

Snippet:

```js
function getCheckedCheckboxesFor(checkboxName) {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="' + checkboxName + '"]:checked'),
    values = [];
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkboxes, function(el) {
    values.push(el.value);
  });
  return values;
}
```

```css
.check-multiple {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.check-multiple input {
  float: left;
}

.check-multiple label {
  display: inline-block;
}

.check-multiple span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.check-multiple input:checked~span {
  background: #03f;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="check-multiple">
  <label for="veh"><input value="car" type="checkbox" name="veh"><span>car</span></label>
  <label for="veh"><input value="scooter" type="checkbox" name="veh"><span>scooter</span></label>
  <label for="veh"><input value="bus" type="checkbox" name="veh"><span>bus</span></label>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="alert(getCheckedCheckboxesFor('veh'));" value="Get Values" />
```

Comment: This seems to work fine. I am getting selected checkbox's value in alert on button click. What exactly do you want?

Comment: @prady its working. but i want to show the selected values on button.

Comment: ok then refer to below answer.

Comment: @prady can I get these values on button without clicking over the button?

Comment: Just to tell you, as you may have not seen it. I updated my answer and added another snippet with some more code to work with multiple elements!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your comments,
here is probably what you want to achieve:

```js
// Added this:
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
checkboxes.forEach(function(chkbx) {
  chkbx.onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("button").value = getCheckedCheckboxesFor(chkbx.name);
  }
})

// Simplified a little this:
function getCheckedCheckboxesFor(name) {
  var checkeds = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="' + name + '"]:checked'),
    values = [];
  checkeds.forEach(function(chkd) {
    values.push(chkd.value);
  });
  return values;
}
```

```css
.check-multiple {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.check-multiple input {
  float: left;
}

.check-multiple label {
  display: inline-block;
}

.check-multiple span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.check-multiple input:checked~span {
  background: #03f;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="check-multiple">
  <label for="veh"><input value="car" type="checkbox" name="veh"><span>car</span></label>
  <label for="veh"><input value="scooter" type="checkbox" name="veh"><span>scooter</span></label>
  <label for="veh"><input value="bus" type="checkbox" name="veh"><span>bus</span></label>
</div>
<input id="button" type="button" onclick="alert(getCheckedCheckboxesFor('veh'));" value="Get Values" />
```

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

Then, as you MUST want to use this code on multiple elements, I did the following:

- As you should avoid inline JavaScript, I removed the function call from the HTML,
- I added a `data` attribute on the buttons, and some other `forEach()` to work with multiple elements,
- I added a 'None selected' when you tick and then untick something. (I didn't like having an empty button),
- I've also added the `disabled` property when 'None selected', just because we can.

Here is a working snippet with all of it:

```js
// Added this
// Made it for multiples, too!
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]');
checkboxes.forEach(function(chkbx, index) {
  chkbx.onchange = function() {
    var name = chkbx.name;
    var button = document.querySelector('input[type=button][data=' + name + ']')
    button.value = getCheckedCheckboxesFor(name);
    
    // Added some code to modify button if no checkbox is selected
    button.removeAttribute("disabled");
    if (button.value == '') {
      button.value = 'None selected';
      button.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    }
  }
})

// As you should avoid inline JS, added this too:
buttons.forEach(function(button, index) {
  button.onclick = function() {
    var name = this.getAttribute('data'); // Get data attribute
    alert(getCheckedCheckboxesFor(name));
  }
})

// Simplified a little this one:
function getCheckedCheckboxesFor(name) {
  var checkeds = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="' + name + '"]:checked'),
    values = [];
  checkeds.forEach(function(chkd) {
    values.push(chkd.value);
  });
  return values;
}
```

```css
.check-multiple {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.check-multiple input {
  float: left;
}

.check-multiple label {
  display: inline-block;
}

.check-multiple span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.check-multiple input:checked~span {
  background: #03f;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="check-multiple">
  <label for="veh"><input value="car" type="checkbox" name="veh"><span>car</span></label>
  <label for="veh"><input value="scooter" type="checkbox" name="veh"><span>scooter</span></label>
  <label for="veh"><input value="bus" type="checkbox" name="veh"><span>bus</span></label>
</div>
<br>
<input data="veh" type="button" value="Select to get values" disabled/>
<br>
<br>
<div class="check-multiple">
  <label for="veh"><input value="car" type="checkbox" name="veh2"><span>car</span></label>
  <label for="veh"><input value="scooter" type="checkbox" name="veh2"><span>scooter</span></label>
  <label for="veh"><input value="bus" type="checkbox" name="veh2"><span>bus</span></label>
</div>
<br>
<input data="veh2" type="button" value="Select to get values" disabled/>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Era Glad it helps! I just added a 'None selected' when you tick and then untick something. (I didn't like having an empty button).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit weird formulated, is this what you are trying to accomplish?

EDIT: used onchange event to trigger the changing value of the button text on the checkboxes

```js
function getCheckedCheckboxesFor(checkboxName) {
  
}

function myFunction(val) {
   var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="' + val + '"]:checked'),
    values = [];
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkboxes, function(el) {
    values.push(el.value);
    
  });
  
    document.getElementById("demo").value = values;

}
```

```css
.check-multiple {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.check-multiple input {
  float: left;
}

.check-multiple label {
  display: inline-block;
}

.check-multiple span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.check-multiple input:checked~span {
  background: #03f;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="check-multiple">
  <label for="veh"><input value="car" type="checkbox" name="veh" onchange="myFunction('veh')"><span>car</span></label>
  <label for="veh"><input value="scooter" type="checkbox" name="veh" onchange="myFunction('veh')"><span>scooter</span></label>
  <label for="veh"><input value="bus" type="checkbox" name="veh" onchange="myFunction('veh')"><span>bus</span></label>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="alert(getCheckedCheckboxesFor('veh'));" value="Get Values" id="demo" />
```

Comment: how can I get these values on button without clicking on it :D

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have up voted your answer. this is exactly what i wanted. but Takit Isy have done it more cautiously. So, selecting his answer.

Comment: @Era I have seen his answer and I agree with your opinion, his function is indeed cleaner written :).